# azure web app loaded from github repo based on spring boot problem

Tags: azure-web-app-service

yesterday i linked my github to an azure web app service
my repo built with rest requests and some of them is working with loading data from firestore based databased , i ran it all on localhost on the tomcat embedded server that comes with spring
,got the web app in the air and my post request which getting resource from firebase , the post request got me an internal 500 server so i check the app insights feature to check what exception i get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:165)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:136)
```

my init code for fire base is:

```
 package Model;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

@Service
public class FBInitialize {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            String fileName = "name of json file with Credential.json";
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource(fileName)).getFile());
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file);
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://qr-database-my data base url")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i checked on the logs and i did got the request i just getting this exception is anyone ever encounter
this exception ?
by the way on initiazlizeApp method the getIntstance methood is being called.

Edit:
found where the exception was thrown from :

```
public static FirebaseApp getInstance(@NonNull String name) {
            synchronized(appsLock) {
                FirebaseApp firebaseApp = (FirebaseApp)instances.get(normalize(name));
                if (firebaseApp != null) {
                    return firebaseApp;
                } else {
                    List<String> availableAppNames = getAllAppNames();
                    String availableAppNamesMessage;
                    if (availableAppNames.isEmpty()) {
                        availableAppNamesMessage = "";
                    } else {
                        availableAppNamesMessage = "Available app names: " + Joiner.on(", ").join(availableAppNames);
                    }
    
                    String errorMessage = String.format("FirebaseApp with name %s doesn't exist. %s", name, availableAppNamesMessage);
                    throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the source code version on github. Please check `build.gradle` file under `android/app` folder.

Add the following line:

```
apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Related Posts:

[1. How to solve Exception Error: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383679/how-to-solve-exception-error-firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist)

[2. FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score -1):

im working with maven , also i figured it out that its has something with the json file with the google credentials location because repackaging the file changing the root content to BOOT-INF so i took the json file content put it in a String and cast it to Inputstream so the Initializeapp and the init would be independent but it still no joy :(

new update:
now i get a different exception I think its about security

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
```

agian im working with maven and not on android